# Thieving/Sneaking Glitch?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Sometimes, when I jump off a tall rock or exit a cave while sneaking, when I exit or land, I will still be sneaking but the crosshairs will appear to be not the shut eye, but the normal crosshairs. Is there a way to fix this? It does not allow you to stand up, or run while like this. I have to re-enter the cave or jump off another rock to get it back to normal again.

P.S. For jumping off a rock, you must take some form of fall damage.

Comment: are you sure attempting to enter sneak again doesn't fix this?  I've ran into this before and retoggling sneak fixed the issue for me.  Also try doing this in third person view so you can be sure if you've stopped sneaking.

Comment: This also happens if you mine something while sneaking, use most of the work benches, etc. But as @yx has mentioned, you can usually just toggle back into sneak mode (you wont crouch again or the like, but the cross-hair will return to sneak mode)

Comment: @James you are right, that's when I encounter it the most.  Its always funny to stop and mine while sneaking through a dungeon yet no one hears your tap tap tap noises.

Answer (score 3):

This happens to me too, i just draw an arrow stand up and down a few times and seathe it and it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

If you have the vanguard add-on, you can become a vampire, change, then change back. I think the same would work for a werewolf.